# Why does $\frac{1 - 3^{k + 1}}{1 - 3} = \frac{3^{k + 1} - 1}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have the following equation:

$$\frac{1 - 3^{k + 1}}{1 - 3} = \frac{3^{k + 1} - 1}{2}$$

Can you explain why the left-hand side of the question is equal to the right side of the equation?

Comment: You're more likely to get a good response if you describe your attempts and your thoughts about the problems, and what specifically you got stuck on.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $1-3=-2$ and $1-3^{k+1}=-(3^{k+1}-1)$.

Answer (score -1):

Realise that:

> **1-3=-2**

We can then take:

> **[-(3^(k+1)-1)]/-2**

The negatives cancel each other, thus the LHS=RHS equation.